# Access OnBindViewholder Elements From Another AdapterClass

Tags: android

I am populating a bottomsheet dialog on `onBindViewHolder` item click, Inside the bottomsheet diolog there is an `Edittext`

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

 holder.img_arrow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            final BottomSheetDialog dialog3 = new BottomSheetDialog(context);
            dialog3.setContentView(R.layout.bcs_report_bottomsheet);
            final EditText etReport = (EditText) dialog3.findViewById(R.id.etReport);
            dialog3.show();
       }); 


}
```

Now I am trying to access this `edittext` from different adapter `bindData` method to set some value inside the edittext but it is giving error `error: incompatible types: Context cannot be converted to DataAdapter_Questions`

```
   void bindData(final MovieModel movieModel){

   tvReply.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            
            ((DataAdapter_Questions) itemView.getRootView().getContext()).etReport.setText(movieModel.submitted_by+",");
      });
            
}
```

how to resolve this issue?

Comment: An adapter isn't a view in the hierarchy, it just does the job of providing views to be added to the hierarchy. So retrieving the adapter won't help, it's like trying to wash your hands with a soap dispenser. Your adapters should be backed with some data, a list of elements etc which can be modified. I would recommend taking a look at some `RecyclerView` tutorials and going from there!

Comment: thanks, is there any  solution to access this?

Comment: You should handle the click in the fragment, not the adapter itself. Then update the data of the second adapter from there.